# Running NuGet in OpenSuse

Tags: mono, nuget, opensuse

I am trying to run NuGet.exe (Nuget BootStrapper) in OpenSuse using mono. I am following article mentioned [here](http://monomvc.wordpress.com/) . But I am facing problem. When I try to run NuGet.exe using mono it gives error that NuGet Package Restore is not enable, please enable it using Visual Studio or set Environment variable. Obviously I don't have Visual Studio in Linux so I am trying to set Environment variable using export. But I am still getting same error.

I am stuck there.

Please let me know if any further information required.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because of NuGet Package Restore requiring consent. More information on this package restore consent can be found here: http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html

By default, package restore is using the `NuGet.exe install` command with the `-RequireConsent` option ([command reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command)). You can find this in the `NuGet.targets` MSBuild file in the $(SolutionDir).nuget folder (default). Simply **remove the -RequireConsent option**.

If you are not using the -RequireConsent option, NuGet package restore should not be looking for the environment variable and your issue should no longer exist.

Comment: No luck... I have tried rebuilding bootstrapper project, even give hardcode value in Programme.cs but then it starts giving file access denied issue.